# How do I set the exception type in Application Insights when raising an error using the NodeJS SDK?

Tags: node.js, azure-application-insights

My app has lots of custom error types which are subclasses of Error. Application Insights logs the exception type in the portal but so far though I have only been able to get it to show a generic 'Error' for the type.

[image]

Looking at the source it seems that setting the error's `name` property should set this, however it makes no difference.

[image]

I have tried sending the following but it does not log as MyError,

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor (msg) {
    super(msg)
    this.name = 'MyError'
  }
}

const error = new MyError('some message')

client.trackException({ exception: error, properties: { correlationId } })
```

I am using version 1.2.0 of the Azure NodeJS SDK

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should let you change the exception type and how you've done it seems correct. I slightly modified your example to be standalone as below.

```html
const appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup('ikey')
  .setInternalLogging(true, true)
  .start();
appInsights.defaultClient.config.maxBatchSize = 1;

class MyError extends Error {
  constructor (msg) {
    super(msg)
    this.name = 'MyError'
  }
}

const error = new MyError('some message')

appInsights.defaultClient.trackException({ exception: error });
```

Comment: Does this work? Did you see the error type set to 'MyError' in Application Insights?

Comment: OK, I've tested the code now and it seems to be working - I'm not sure what has changed. It definitely helped setting the batch size to 1 for more immediate feedback

Comment: Yes it did end up working. I added some pictures to the github issue for what to look for in a debugger in case you are looking into this still.
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/499

Answer (score 0):

Depending on execution context errors are handled differently. There is no real standard about that. Previously I found usefull help in mozilla pages: [Error management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

Sorry I don't have any repo with a well writen example since I choose to not use perso-typed errors anymore.

Comment: Its not about Javascript errors, its about ApplicationInsights